# prevent double backslashes on update insert

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql, asp.net-mvc-4, npgsql

I am saving an UNC path in my PostgresSQL db. am using for this Entity Framework(+NpgSQL) like :

```
            var p = context.Parametres.Find(25);
            p.UncPath = p.UncPath + @"\aFolder\for\test";
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Initialy i have this

```
      UncPath = "\\uncServer\Docs_storage\sub"
```

but after update i get this :

```
      UncPath = "\\\\uncServer\\Docs_storage\\sub\\aFolder\\for\\test"
```

second update :

```
      UncPath = "\\\\\\uncServer\\\\Docs_storage\\\\sub\\\\aFolder\\\\for\\\\test"
```

any ideas to fix this?
thx

**EDIT:**
PostgreSQL 9.2
npgsql 2.0.12.0
standard_conforming_strings is commented on postgresql.conf
log_statement  is commented on postgresql.conf

Comment: What's your PostgreSQL version and `standard_conforming_strings` setting? What nPgSQL version? What's the actual SQL generated and run by Entity Framework? (Get it from the PostgreSQL logs - enable `log_statement = 'all'` - or from nPgSQL's logs)

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.2
npgsql 2.0.12.0
standard_conforming_strings is commented on postgresql.conf
log_statement is commented on postgresql.conf

Comment: I mentioned `log_statement` because I was suggesting you could use it as a way to get the actual SQL that your program runs. Which you need to get, and add to this question. Without the actual SQL getting run it will be difficult to help you.